# Why does Rename fails with Python files if there is no trailing space?

Tags: vimrc, plugin-python-mode

`:Rename` (from [vim-rename](https://vim.sourceforge.io/scripts/script.php?script_id=1928)) fails with Python files in my current set up with the following error:

```
line   46:
E486: Pattern not found: \s\+$
```

if the file does not contain trailing whitespaces in at least one line, leading to the file being duplicated (with the new name and the old one).

Using the following file `helloworld.py` (note there are no trailing whitespaces):

```
print("Hello, world!")
```

If I attempt to use `:Rename new_name.py` it will spew out the previously-mentioned error, and I'll end up with two files (`helloworld.py` and `new_name.py`). If, however, I add whitespaces at the end of the line, the renaming will succeed and the trailing whitespaces are automatically removed.

This seems to be due to some sort of conflict between `vim-rename` and [`python-mode`](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode/), since it only happens with Python files.

After debugging what happens on a write with `:debug write`, I can see that `pymode#trim_whitespaces()` is invoked by default by `python-mode`. If I disable it by `let g:pymode_trim_whitespaces=0`, the problem with `vim-rename` goes away. However, automatic trimming of trailing whitespaces is a feature I don't want to lose.

My questions, in order of importance:

1. **How can I fix this so that I can rename files and keep the automatic trimming of whitespaces?**
2. **Why is the non-existence of whitespaces causing rename to fail?**

I would prefer to keep `vim-rename`, although I'm willing to switch it for a more robust plugin if necessary. Fixing the code in `vim-rename` manually would also be acceptable.

If it is of any use, [this](https://pastebin.com/55uxuT0P) is my complete `vimrc` file.

Comment: As you said the problem comes from somewhere in your vimrc which makes your question pretty much a duplicate of [How do I debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841)

Comment: @statox Thanks for the suggestion. I have debugged my vimrc and confirmed my suspicions, but knowing what the problem is doesn't mean I know how to fix it, so I don't think it's a duplicate. I'll update the answer, though.

Comment: If you found which line of configuration or which plugin creates the error message then you can indeed edit your question so that we can help you with this particular line/plugin, otherwise your question is still about debugging your vimrc.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've done. The problem seems to be that `python-mode` automatically trims whitespaces on save. I am not sure why that would cause the deletion of the old file to fail, but it does.

Comment: Indeed with your edit the question isn't a duplicate anymore. I think you should also try to contact the authors of the plugin via their issue tracker, maybe you'll get an answer faster than on here.

Comment: I tried before posting here, but the plugin is super small (~90 lines) and it has been inactive for almost 7 years, and their GitHub does not have an issues tab :(

Comment: As a workaround you can try https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch plugin, which has `Rename` as well (but please see README for difference between `Rename` and `Move`)

Comment: I'm the author of Rename.vim (although there are forks of it out there).  As @Rich mentions in their answer, this is an issue with the BufWritePre autocmd and function that the python-mode plugin defines, and the suggestion to add an `e` flag to the substitute command will fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not clear on why the problem occurs — the [line in `pymode#trim_whitespaces()` that is triggering the error](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode/blob/d2dead6ce9d900b26dbf1a06c52969f4194eda64/autoload/pymode.vim#L74) includes a `silent!` so the error should be ignored. You could maybe try appending an `e` flag to ignore the errors more specifically:

```
silent! %s/\s\+$//e
```

If that works, you should probably report it to the author of python-mode.

However, I'm not too motivated to dig any deeper into what's going wrong, because there's a very simple workaround, which is to write a new command which turns off "trim whitespaces" before running the rename and then restores it afterwards.

```
function! MyRename(new_name, bang)
  if exists("g:pymode_trim_whitespaces")
    let orig_trim_whitespaces = g:pymode_trim_whitespaces
  endif
  let g:pymode_trim_whitespaces = 0

  execute "Rename" . a:bang . " " . a:new_name

  if exists("orig_trim_whitespaces")
    let g:pymode_trim_whitespaces = orig_trim_whitespaces
  else
    unlet g:pymode_trim_whitespaces
  endif
endfunction

command! -nargs=* -complete=file -bang MyRename call MyRename(<q-args>, '<bang>')
```

You've also indicated that you're happy to edit the code of `vim-rename`, so an even quicker (but even more hacky) fix would be simply to add the lines that set and reset `g:pymode_trim_whitespaces` at appropriate places in the Rename() function itself. (i.e. just before and after the line that performs the rename (`silent! exe 'saveas' . a:bang . ' ' . l:name`).

Comment: I have opened an issue on python-mode with your suggested fix.

Comment: Thank you to both :) I have switched to `tpope/vim-eunuch`, which works fine, but this answer gives a solution that keeps the same plugin and explains what goes wrong, so accepted!

Comment: For future reference, the issue is https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode/issues/797 and it has been resolved :D